# Kernel Module: Netfilter hook not providing correct data via sk_buff

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

I have a linux kernel module that needs to process the data received via netfilter hook as a socket buffer.

This is what I am doing in the callback,

```
unsigned char *eth = skb_mac_header(skb);
int len = skb->len + 14; //Assuming eth is 14 bytes. Neglecting VLAN case. 

for (int j=0; j < len; j++)
{
     printk("%X ", eth[j]);
}
```

On receiving packets, i get correct length. However he packet contents for some UDP traffic has only correct 48 bytes (initial) and rest of the bytes are not what my interface is receiving. User-space application is receiving correct packet contents as being received on the interface.

Can anyone help explain that what I am doing wrong. Help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

skb_mac_header(skb) gives you the pointer to the mac header. It's valid length is skb->mac_len.

If you need to dump the user data (payload), you may print each char from skb->data to skb->tail. The following link shows the skb data layout: http://vger.kernel.org/~davem/skb_data.html.

Comment: Thanks Denkie. Just tried that. The skb->data has only 6 bytes correct for data i am testing against. This is same as 48 bytes - (14 + 20 + 8 of network headers). I believe there is something else.

Comment: It could be a limitation of netfilter. NetFilter might have to act on the packet header to reduce latency, thus, the hook may be called before the complete packet data has been received. Another possibility is fragmentation. The packet data might not be complete yet due to packet fragmentation.